# STORAGE_USAGE view breakdown by table/schema/database over time?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

From "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."STORAGE_USAGE", **I'd like to see the TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES broken out from 'STORAGE_BYTES' over time, by table** and/or database. As it exists today, TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES and ACTIVE_BYTES are bundled up and combined into the existing field, 'STORAGE_BYTES'.

I've tried using "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS" to access this information, but it seems that this can only show me the TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES at the exact moment of querying.

Has anyone had success finding a way to breakout this usage data? If so, please let me know how it's done!

Comment: You should request this functionality directly to Snowflake.  This information is not currently available at the detail you want it and historically, but I've seen others requesting it, as well.  The only way to do this would be to build it yourself using a task to insert "current records" into a separate table with a timestamp.